# What is this.$() in Ember or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I saw example code on https://github.com/lukemelia/jquery-ui-ember. Can some one tell me what is **this.$()**

you can see this on jquery-ui-ember-master\jquery-ui-ember-master\js\app.js

Comment: If `this` is the global object, then `this.$()` will be equivalent to `window.$()`, which in turn can shortened into plain `$()`.

Answer (score 5):

> **`this.$()` is a call of the `$`-method of your current objectscope.**

`this` refers to your current object.
`$` is a function of `this`.
`()` will call the function `$` of `this`.

Comment: Which gives you the reference to the jQuery object.

Comment: @mlienau: Nope. `this.$()` would return a new instance of an empty jQuery object in this case.

Comment: Since this question is in the context of Ember, Leeft's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a [`Component`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html), in its code `this.$()` gives you a jQuery object reference, set to the element that was inserted into the dom by that `Component` (its outer tag, usually a `div` unless you told it otherwise). You can then use for example `this.$('.myclass')` to find the element with the class `myclass` within the section of HTML that is handled by that `Component` without having to specify an `id` attribute to find the correct set of elements.

This probably also applies to the `View`s, but you should be using a `Component` instead whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

As Leeft said `this.$()` will give you the reference to the jQuery object, but typically you should only want to get the reference to the jQuery object in `didInsertElement` where the component has been inserted into the DOM and you can do jQuery-UI stuff on the element.

Comment: Like I already said: Nope. this.$() would return a new instance of an empty jQuery object. The source for the $-Function is: `function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}` => No referenced returned here.